# JavaScript on submit click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to show a div on click of a submit button but when I am submitting the div is shown for the moment till the page reloads. After the page reload the div fades away. I need to stop that fading. How to do it in JavaScript?

The code is as:

```
<div class="main" align="center" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Report Generation'">
      <form  action="response.jsp"  method="post">
      <h2></h2>
      <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" id="sel" name="sel" required="true">
      <option value=""><---Select the Sources---></option>
      <option value="">All</option>
     <% String tss=fa.myresult();
                %>
       <option value=""><%=tss%></option>
      </select><br><br>
      <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" id="linkrec" name="linkrec" required="true">
      <option value=""><---Select The Operation---></option>
      <option value="">Linkages</option>
      <option value="">Total No. of records</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="Submit" onClick=check();>Search</button></form>
      </div>
      <div class="child" id="p2" style="display:none" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Result'">
      <%     String a1=fa.getsrc();
            String name=request.getParameter("sel");
            String src=request.getParameter("linkrec");%>
            The Selected source is ---><%=name %><br><br>
        <b>The Selected operation is--><%=src %></b><br>
        <b>The Source <%=name%> Has <%=src%>---><%=a1%></b>
        
        </div>

 <script>
      
      function check()
      {
          usersrc=document.getElementById("sel").value;
          userselect=document.getElementById("linkrec").value;
         
         if(usersrc=="<---Select the Sources--->"|| userselect=="<---Select The Operation--->")
              {
              alert("Select src and records");
              }
        else if (usersrc=="All" && userselect=="Linkages")
             {
             document.getElementById('p2').style.display ='';
             }</script>
```

Comment: `return false` in your submit callback.

Comment: Post some codes what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **return false** to your onSubmit

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" onclick="return showdiv();"/>
```

** in javascript**

```
function showdiv()
{
     var error = false;
    //validate your form.
    if(error == true){ return true;}
    else
    {
       //show div
       return false;
    }
}
```